# Persisting data for question type plugin in moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I am developing a new question type plugin for Moodle. It is multiple choice question. I need to add some specific data to the answers of the question, based on the original question answer defined by the teacher and display the updated answer text to the student taking the test.

Let's say it is a random number in interval defined in the answer text. The main idea is that my question type should generate different answers in different quizes for the same question, but the answers should be the same withing given quiz instance so when going back and next between the quiz pages and when reviewing the answers after finish the question text should not different.

So as I suppose I should persist the updated answer text for the current quiz instance, without modifying the DB.

I have tried to do this in may ways, I have tried to store this info in question attempt step instance, to persist it in the question instance and even in the question type instance. I also tried to do this in custom renderer.  But it seems that all of them are reinitialized in each refresh or next/previous question move.

As I suppose it should be similar to generating the order of the questions or keeping the selected answer but I can not achieve it.

Can someone explain me how to achieve that or point me to a resource where I can read more about question attempt steps or other mechanism how to persist  the needed data.

Thanks,

Kamen.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing your own qtype why not create your own table where you store these generated values and populate it with data when new question instance is created?

The structure may be as follows:

id INT
qattemptid INT
answerid INT
answerdata MIXED (depends an data type you assume to show)

Best documentation to start with is [this one](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Overview_of_the_Moodle_question_engine)

Comment: thanks for the response. I don't want to persist this data in the Database since it will produce unneeded amount of data in it and also will be slower to retrieve. I need it persisted only in the current session. I think that 2 days ago I managed to do this. Still not have applied the whole logic behind it, but seems like it is working. Will explain my solution once I am sure that it works correctly.